# Windows 8 Upgrade - Can I install it not using older system?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, upgrade

If I buy cheap upgrade version of Windows 8 Pro I can install it on older Windows 7 Home Premium, right? I've seen [Upgrade Assistant](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-assistant-download-online-faq) from Microsoft support page but still have some questions.

What if I want to install that Windows 8 Upgrade version on clean disk? Do I need to first install older system just to update it to newer? Or this upgrade option means I can get new system cheaper becaouse I own older?

Is there a difference if my previous sytem was BOX or OEM?

PS Why Windows 8.1 is more expensive than Windows 8? Is it a selling trick?

Comment: Of course you can there are several versions of this exact question on this website.  Compare a system build license to a 8.1 license it's near the price 8.0 isn't sold by MS

Comment: The upgrade requires a previous supported version of windows to upgrade to 8.0.  8.1 is an upgrade from 7 or clean install

Comment: Requires it where? As an licence or installed on disk?

Comment: The upgrade license can only be used to upgrade a previous installation of Windows.  You can of course choose to do a clean installation if you want instead of doing an upgrade installation.  Windows 8.0 Professional ( System Builder ) is within $10 of Windows 8.1 Professional you have to compare apples to apples.  You can't compare Windows 8.0 Professional Upgrade license to any Windows 8.1 license since nothing like the Upgrade license exists within the 8.1 family.

Comment: But can I do upgrade out of clean disk without need to install previous system.

Comment: **You can't** At least not with a `Windows 8.0 Upgrade` license which is what your asking about.

Answer (score -1):

It is always adviseable to do a clean install .Sometimes computer to computer may differ problems .

windows 8 wasnt actually final tooo .. but with all the fixes and patches its very much imrpoved . Whenever a new version is released there will be some bugs . it will take some time for the OEM to give their suggestions to microsoft .

Windows 8.1 is the most current version and it is final .So its more worth a high price than incomeplete windows 8.

Comment: I can upgrade Windows 8 to 8.1 for free than price difference is cheaty. How to do "clean" install with upgrade version?

Comment: @user272835 - This has to be worst advice I have ever read on this website.  There is **NOTHING** wrong about doing an upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 8.0.  Infact the incorrect claim you should do clean installation has not been since since the release of Windows Vista.  The previous process of upgrading Windows 95/98 to Windows XP was indeed not good for a good number of reasons.

Comment: @user272835 - **You run the setup while within Windows and do that option.**